# SQL Server: copy a row and insert into a new row with a different ID

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy a row from a given table and insert into a new row in the same table with  a different ID for a column.

**query:**

```
INSERT INTO ESurvey_Question(QuestionTypeID, Question, HoriVertID, IsMandatory, FillIn, QuestionRank, Choice_Limit,SurveyID )
   SELECT 
       QuestionTypeID, Question, HoriVertID, IsMandatory, FillIn, QuestionRank, 
       Choice_Limit, @NewSUID as SurveyID 
   FROM ESurvey_Question 
   WHERE SurveyID = @ExistingSUID

@ExistingSUID= 64
@@NewSUID = 115
```

Here `SurveyID` is the foreign key, and I want to change it with the new ID.

`QuestionID` is the primary key (`IDENTTITY`).

I am getting this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. 
>   This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem...is there more to your query that you're not showing? That error occurs when you use a subquery, and I don't see one here.

Answer (score 0):

I tested a similar statement on my local machine and dont get any errors. However, your error message tells us you are using a subquery, but you arent actually doing that here.

Is there some code missing? Maybe `SurveyID = @ExistingSUID` is set via subquery? If so, as the error message tells, there cant be more than one result. (If you need this, use `SurveyID IN ...`